# the difference between summing up sentence.count(x) and len(sentence)

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
f = open("C:/Python27/Brown.txt", 'rU')
raw = f.read()
sent = re.sub(r'[^\sa-zA-Z]', '', raw).upper().strip()
count_A = sent.count('A')
count_B = sent.count('B')
......
count_Z = sent.count('Z')
count_Blank = sent.count(' ')
count_All = len(sent)
```

Here I think I remained only space and alpha characters, so if I sum up the count_A, count_B, count_C...count_Blank should be equal as len(sent), isn't it? but when I compare two values, it was not. Why this happen? Actually I need Probability of letter "A", "B", "C"..."Blank", but don't know what value to divide, len(sent)? or summing up count_A to count_Blank.

Comment: Have you had a look at `Counter` objects from the [`collections` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?  Following those examples, you should be able to do `Counter(list(sent))` then query the returned dict for specific letter counts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have counted only spaces using `sent.count(' ')`, i am assuming `sent` has newline(s) and/or tab(s) associated with it.

Do count for tabs:

```
sent.count('\t')
```

and newlines:

```
sent.count('\n')
```